# AWS ElasticBeanstalk update without modifing Django wsgi.conf

Tags: python, django, apache, amazon-web-services, mod-wsgi

I have a django app deployed in AWS EB using autoscaling.
This app uses Django Rest with Token Authentication.
In order for this to work, I have to add the following lines in etc/httpd/conf.d/wsgi.conf file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
RewriteRule .* - [e=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]

WSGIPassAuthorization On
```

The problem is: when AWS do an autoscale or ElasticBeanstalk environment upgrade, the wsgi.conf file is updated and the custom settings are deleted.

How can I avoid that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To avoid ElasticBeanstalk erasing your custom settings while autoscaling or re-initializing any instance in your environment you should use your `.ebextensions` scripts to do any durable modification to your ec2 instance's `config` files.

(After having tested these modifications as you did 'manually' using `eb ssh`)

In that case you could use for example a `sed command` to edit your `wsgi.conf` file.

add the following container_command to one of you your yaml Elastic Beanstalk configuration file (ie: `.ebextension/yourapp.config`):

`03_wsgipass:
    command: 'sed -i -f .ebextensions/wsgi_update.sed ../wsgi.conf'`

It should then look like this :

```
container_commands:
  01_migrate:
    command: "django-admin.py migrate --noinput"
    leader_only: true
  02_collectstatic:
    command: "django-admin.py collectstatic --noinput"
  03_wsgipass:
    command: 'sed -i -f .ebextensions/wsgi_update.sed ../wsgi.conf'
```

create a new file in `wsgi_update.sed` in the `.ebextensions` folder with the following content:

```
/<Virtual/ a\
RewriteEngine On\
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)\
RewriteRule .* - [e=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]

/<\/Virtual/ a\
WSGIPassAuthorization On
```

This is a small [sed program](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#sed-Programs) for example that will add the apache `mod_rewrite` rules inside your `<VirtualHost>` block and the `WSGIPassAuthorization` line after the closing tag `</VirtualHost>` in your `wsgi.conf` file

It will be executed on each application deployment to any existing or new instances created by autoscaling in your environment.

see [Using the AWS Elastic Beanstalk Python Platform](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-container.html#create-deploy-python-custom-container) for more info

Answer (score 0):

This is not working i have tried all options nothing seems to work with ebs. I don't really know what else to try.

Comment: This is not an answer. Please move to a comment.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31031694)